# Finding last column of data table and storing as a variable in excel macro vba

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have some code in excel that stores an entire table in a variable. It looks like this:

```
vLookLastRow = Worksheets("worksheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

vLookLastCol = Worksheets("worksheet1").Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set vLookRange = Worksheets("worksheet1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(vLookLastRow, vLookLastCol)
```

This means when I return vLookRange.address, I get "$A$1:$S$383" as my output, which is the entire table.

I would like an output that gives me the last column +1, so if my table is from column A to S and rows 1 to 383, I would like an output of $T$2:$T$383

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to do so.
The following code starts with cell `Cells(2, vLookLastCol+1)`
You want to start with row 2, so the first parameter to `Cells` is 2.
As `vLookLastCol` has the number of the last column of your table (19 for column `S`), `vLookLastCol+1` is the column number of the next column (`T`).

So `Cells(2, vLookLastCol+1)` is cell `T2`.
Now we use `Resize`, but we resize only the number of rows. `vLookLastRow` is 383, but we started with row 2 so we need to subtract 1.

```
With Worksheets("worksheet1")
    vLookLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    vLookLastCol = .Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set vLookRange = .Cells(2, vLookLastCol+1).Resize(vLookLastRow-1, 1)
End With
```

An alternative is to use the `Range`-Function with 2 parameters, defining the start and the end cell:

```
Set vLookRange = .Range(.Cells(2, vLookLastCol+1), .Cells(vLookLastRow, vLookLastCol+1))
```

Comment: Thats great! Thank you so much, seems like it was quite an easy fix - i was focussing more on the "resize" part, rather than the "cells" part :)